# why offset grid props does not work sometimes in react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am faced with a frequent problem in react botostrap,sometimes grid offset props does not work, and only normal bootstrap classes work for me.

code:

```
<Carousel.Item >
    <div className="item-container d-flex flex-column flex-wrap ">
       {
          this.categories.map(category => {
             return (
               <Card  className="px-2 category__card col-xl-4 col-sm-6">
                  <div className=" car-container" style={category.style}>
                      <Card.Body>
                         <Card.Title className="text-white font-weight-normal text-uppercase ">
                             <h3>
                                {category.title}
                             </h3>
                           </Card.Title>
                          <Button variant="light rounded-0" >View Products</Button>    
                       </Card.Body>
                       <Card.Img variant="bottom" src={category.img} className="card-image"/>


                   </div>  

                 </Card>
               );
            })
          }
     </div>
 </Carousel.Item>
```

This code works as i used normal bootstrap classes in **Card** component `col-xl-4 col-sm-6` but it does not work when i remove these classes and use react-bootstrap props `sm={6} xl={4}`

I can use bootstrap classes and be happy but i need to make the width of the cards in carousel item dynamic so why i am asking the question, what may be the reasons behind these props does not work???